# A client error (InvalidCiphertextException) occurred when calling the Decrypt operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kms

When I am trying to execute the command:

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://CPOEncrypted.txt --output text --query Plaintext
```

I am getting the below error and I am suspecting that ciphertext issue.

```
A client error (InvalidCiphertextException) occurred when calling the Decrypt operation:
```

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Make sure your aws is configured on pc, AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key are set. To configure it - run in console:

```
$ aws configure
```

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

**2.** make sure the file is correct. I had the same issue because some part of BASE64 was missed during copy-paste - so BASE64 code was incorrect.
Now it works fine.I use this command for file creation where code is 
client_secret encoded in Base64 format (letters and numbers of code were randomly changed in example of course):

```
$echo ZPATMQE/c3o06DQL0FnZn1Q04Ojh8JbKh87gNohFJFvJ8L456JGFFDhtscGHDjOhbnwKDJnUnK5lkjOJHFDkGuyhgouyfk2YFhgfgffftftDTDBtdbItydbtDbtd65Hf654521JHJHFJGSJFAlc3Qhgb4/s3daa435KHGJGjhgf+as54asd54DKUGdasd54asd5DFf+a54faas65454asUHgTm+a | base64 -di > encrypted-file
```

**3.** Then I use this command in console to get the final result:

```
$ echo $(aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://encrypted-file --query Plaintext --output text | base64 -di)
```

Comment: I had to remove the `i` from the base64 command; then it worked for me (on OSX)!

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation if you want to use the blob as a `string` and not inside a `.txt`

> aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo "*put the giant blob
> text in here*” | base64 -D) --output text --query Plaintext --region
> us-east-1 | base64 -D

This will decrypt the text and print as output.

Comment: exactly as i wanted. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command on a Windows machine

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob <ENCRYPTED VALUE FROM SECRET MANAGER> --output text --query Plaintext
```

But you can not run in ubuntu. If you run in Ubuntu then mentioned error will occur.
"A client error (InvalidCiphertextException) occurred when calling the Decrypt operation:"